# Assigned numbers to movie clip to plug in formula... not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I am attempting to vertically evenly space these movie clips so I came up with a math formula involving n( the button number) but it's not working.

```
var buttonArray:Array = [side_banner.btn1, side_banner.btn2, side_banner.btn3, side_banner.btn4];

var buttonCount:uint = buttonArray.length;

for (var i:uint = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
  buttonArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, outputNumber);
  buttonArray[i].theTrigger = [i + 1];
}

function outputNumber(e:MouseEvent):void {
  trace( e.target.theTrigger);
  buttonArray[i].y = (((stage.stageHeight - 400)/4)*(e.target.theTrigger)) - ((stage.stageHeight - 400)/4)/2
}
```

But apparently each movie clip doesn't actually have a numerical value just a numeric name... how can I get the "n" btn number to use my formula?

Comment: buttonArray[i].theTrigger = i

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have square brackets where you should have nothing or parens:

```
buttonArray[i].theTrigger = [i + 1];
```

also I don't think button is dynamic so you can't arbitrarily add properties to it however you should be safe in using the data value so long as your buttons aren't directly used as a renderer. Like

```
buttonArray[i].data = i+1;
```